# Material UI withStyles on multiple styled HoCs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My application uses HoCs for its modals and I use withStyles to style them, when I apply multiple HoCs to one component however the classes prop of the first HoC is passed to the next in the compose of the component.

Example HoC1:

```
const styles = themes => ({
    HoCOneStyle: {
        margin: 'auto'
    }
})

const withHoCOne = (WrappedComponent) => {
    class HoCOne extends React.Component {
        <HoC Stuff className={classes.HoCOneStyle} />
        <WrappedComponent
        {...this.props}
        />
    }

    return withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})(HoCOne);
}
export default withHoCOne;
```

Example HoC2:

```
const styles = themes => ({
    HoCTwoStyle: {
        margin: 'auto'
    }
})

const withHoCTwo = (WrappedComponent) => {
    class HoCTwo extends React.Component {
        <HoC Stuff className={classes.HoCTwoStyle} />
        <WrappedComponent
        {...this.props}
        />
    }

    return withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})(HoCTwo);
}
export default withHoCTwo;
```

Example component:

```
class DemoComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Component Stuff />
        )
    }
}

export default compose(
    withHoCOne,
    withHoCTwo
)(DemoComponent)
```

If run this code would throw an error in the console saying:

> Warning: Material-UI: the key 'HoCOneStyle' provided to the classes
>   property is not implemented in HoCTwo. You can only override one of
>   the following: HoCTwoStyle.

How do I avoid throwing this error? It doesn't actually stop anything from working I just don't want errors in my console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to avoid passing the `classes` property from HoCOne into HoCTwo. When you include the `classes` property on something that is also using `withStyles` it triggers Material-UI's [mergeClasses](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui-styles/src/mergeClasses/mergeClasses.js#L31) functionality.

You should be able to solve this with something like the following:

```
render() {
  const {classes, ...otherProps} = this.props;
  return <><HoC className={classes.HoCOneStyle} /><WrappedComponent
        {...otherProps}
        /></>;
}
```